# Tips for refactoring long components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Imagine having a long component, with methods to resolve a use case.

During the development of this component, we might think to refactor it, converting the component into a molecule, with its atoms (children).

So, if we had this original component:

```
function A() {
   const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);

   const myMethod1 = () => {
       setMyState([1]);
   }

   const myMethod2 = () => {
       setMyState([2]);
   }

   ...
   
   const myMethodN = () => {
       setMyState([N]);
   }


   const otherMethod = () => {
       console.log("Hello world");
   }

   useEffect(() => {
       otherMethod();
   }, []);

   return (
     <View>
        {/* STUFF... */}
     </View>
   );
}
```

We could easily refactor, using atoms:

```
function A() {
    function A() {
       const [myState, setMyState] = useState([]);
    
       const myMethod1 = () => {
           setMyState([1]);
       }
    
       const myMethod2 = () => {
           setMyState([2]);
       }
    
       ...
       
       const myMethodN = () => {
           setMyState([N]);
       }
    
       return (
         <View>
            {/* LESS STUFF... */}
            <B />
         </View>
       );
    }
}

function B() {
   const otherMethod = () => {
       console.log("Hello world");
   }

   useEffect(() => {
       otherMethod();
   }, []);

   return (
     <View>
        {/* LESS STUFF... */}
     </View>
   );
}
```

But, sometimes, in some scenarios, it will has no sense to split the component into small fragments.

So, if there were a component with 50 methods inside it like the functions "myMethodN" of the component "A", where it has all the sense of the world to contain all its methods inside it, which types of refactoring could we apply?

I have thought to move parts of the code to custom hooks, or creating "functional/logical" HOCs, to avoid having a component of 500 lines of code. But, seems unnecessary as I will only use these hooks or HOCs with that component (no reusability).

I don't know why, but I feel really stressed, in reactive programming, when I see a long component, and it becomes really hard to apply a refactoring over it, because of the states management, etc. Any rule of thumb or good practice to avoid these kind of situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom hooks are good for reusing them in multiple components but I would also use them in this example because by that code looks more clean and readable even if you will not use hooks again in the future. I prefer hooks more then HOC because when you open component you immediatelly see that there are some custom named hooks, when you use HOC you have to scroll to the bottom of the component to find out that it uses HOC. Sometimes it is not that clear to see it because you see some different props comming to it but you don't know from where do you get them. Later on you see that component is wrapper in HOC but it is not that easy to find out.